# .htaccess redirect homepage only, mask subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect website homepage only to subdomain `/test`, currently I have a header redirect in the index.php file.

Current url is `https://www.website.com/test`

I want to use `.htaccess` to mask subdirectory test in url but still want all other requests go to corresponding destination under root.

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually try to achieve... What exactly do you mean by "mask a subdirectory"? What exactly do you mean by "homepage" here? Why isn't the `/test` path in the URL just fine to tell that part of your service apart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If test is subdirectory you can try this rewrite in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\/$ /test/ [L]
```